# High Standard deviation for regression coefficient in multilevel model with random slopes compared to fixed slopes

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, references, multilevel-analysis

Recently, I compared two multilevel models of the same data:

One with fixed slopes:

R Code:

```r
lmer(RT ~ Kontrast + (1|ID) + (1|Satz),
             data = reading_times,
             REML = FALSE)
```

and one with random slopes:

```r
lmer(RT ~ Kontrast + (Kontrast|ID) + (Kontrast|Satz),
             data = reading_times,
             REML = FALSE)
```

What I found, was that the standard deviation of the regression coefficient of the predictor "Kontrast" was way higher in the second model with random slopes.
It kinda makes sense, because the coefficient can vary between persons(ID) and between sentences ("Satz"), is that the only reason?

Can someone point out good literature for multilevel models with crossed random effects?

Comment: I do not have a strong answer for this. I think some simulation is in order. However, work by Heisig & Schafer that looks at testing interactions between grouping variables and lower level variables suggests that random slopes induce greater uncertainty in the fixed slope estimate. https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Why-You-Should-Always-Include-a-Random-Slope-for-in-Heisig-Schaeffer/4d870d19e543b2e4061e178ee0ec7c66bc237e3a